# How to curl from specific line from website?

Tags: curl

I'am trying to curl from
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw to my file
And I want only ===2018 report=== part

This is what I wrote

```
curl curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw >> a1t4.txt
```

But it take all content from this website what I want is only this part

```
===2018 report===
The 2018 report features the happiness score averaged over the years 2015–2017. As per the 2018 Happiness Index, [[Finland]] is the 'happiest' country in the world. [[Norway]], [[Denmark]], [[Iceland]] and [[Switzerland]] hold the next top positions. The report was published on 14 March 2018 by UN. The full report can be read at [http://worldhappiness.report/ed/2018/ 2018 Report]. The World Happiness Report is a landmark survey of the state of global happiness. The World Happiness Report 2018, which ranks 156 countries by their happiness levels, and 117 countries by the happiness of their immigrants, was released on March 14 at a launch event at the Pontifical Academy of Sciences in the Vatican.
{{collapse top|title=Table}}
{| class="wikitable sortable"
|- valign=top
! style="width: 10px;" | Overall rank
! style="width: 250px;" | Country or region
! {{abbr|Score|Happiness score}}
! style="width: 10px;" | {{abbr|GDP per capita|Explained by: GDP }}
! style="width: 10px;" | {{abbr|Social support|Explained by: Social support}}
! style="width: 10px;" | {{abbr|Freedom to make life choices|Explained by: Freedom to make life choices}}
! style="width: 10px;" | {{abbr|Generosity|Explained by: Generosity}}
! style="width: 10px;" | {{abbr|Perceptions of corruption|Explained by: Perceptions of corruption}}
|-
| 1||{{flag|Finland}}||7.632||1.305||1.592||0.874||0.681||0.202||0.393
|-
| 2||{{flag|Norway}}||7.594||1.456||1.582||0.861||0.686||0.286||0.340
|-
| 3||{{flag|Denmark}}||7.555||1.351||1.590||0.868||0.683||0.284||0.408
|-
| 4||{{flag|Iceland}}||7.495||1.343||1.644||0.914||0.677||0.353||0.138
|-
| 5||{{flag|Switzerland}}||7.487||1.420||1.549||0.927||0.660||0.256||0.357
|-
| 6||{{flag|Netherlands}}||7.441||1.361||1.488||0.878||0.638||0.333||0.295
|-
| 7||{{flag|Canada}}||7.328||1.330||1.532||0.896||0.653||0.321||0.291
|-
| 8||{{flag|New Zealand}}||7.324||1.268||1.601||0.876||0.669||0.365||0.389
|-
| 9||{{flag|Sweden}}||7.314||1.355||1.501||0.913||0.659||0.285||0.383
|-
| 10||{{flag|Australia}}||7.272||1.340||1.573||0.910||0.647||0.361||0.302
```

Comment: you want only top 10 countries or all 2018 report ?

Comment: only top 10 countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `awk`:

```bash
curl -s 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw' \
| awk  '
    /^===2018 report===/{p=1}
    /^\| 11\|\|/{p=0}
    p'
```

- we pipe the output from `curl` to `awk` using `curl ... | awk ...`
- `awk` script will set a variable `p` to `1` (true)  when the beginning of line matches `===2018 report===`, and to `0` (false) when beginning of line matces `|11 ||`. It will print the line whenever `p` is 1.

Comment: Could you please describe you code, I want to understand how it worksTT